# R ggplot: How to create a scatter plot with marginal box plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, scatter-plot, boxplot

My data looks like this:

```
d1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =                   
                   "a1c   att  status
                 8.500000 23.58333  case
                 8.450000 12.25000 control
                 8.266667 18.91667 control")

a1c   att  status
1  8.500000 23.58333  case
2  8.450000 12.25000 control
12 8.266667 18.91667 control
```

I would like to make a boxplot of joint distribution of `a1c` and `att` (say a1c on x axis and att on y axis) and have dots in boxplots colored by `status` in the 3rd column. Say case would be red plots and control blue dots.

So far I tried this:

```
ggplot(data = d1, aes(x = a1c, y = att, group=status)) +     
 geom_boxplot(colour = d1$status) + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(
 width = .1, height=0))
```

I am getting this warnings:

> In addition: Warning messages: 1: Removed 68 rows containing missing
>   values (stat_boxplot).  2: Removed 5 rows containing non-finite values
>   (stat_boxplot).

Thanks,

Comment: So... what do you have so far? This site is for troubleshooting, not for us to do your work for you...

Comment: I tried this:ggplot(data = d1, aes(x = a1c, y = att)) + geom_boxplot(colour = d1$status)

Comment: Also, attach the output or provide the error. Please edit the question by adding these.

Comment: The `geom_boxplot` call needs `aes(color = status)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than way to create scatter plots with marginal boxplots. I know of 2 at least: one with `ggplot` and `ggExtra`, and another one with the package `car`:

your data:

```
d1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
    "a1c   att  status
    8.500000 23.58333  case
    8.450000 12.25000 control
    8.266667 18.91667 control")
```

## ggplot and ggExtra

If you want to use `ggplot` I believe you need `ggExtra` to make this work. The following code does the trick

```
# load the packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)

# make a usual ggplot and store it
# point size increased, legend to the bottom
p1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=a1c, y=att , color=status)) +
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

# marginal boxplot
# relative size of the central plot increased
ggMarginal(p1, type="boxplot", size=7)
```

which results in this graph (of course, you may play around with themes and the like):

[image]

## Alternative: the car package

```
library(car)
scatterplot(d1$a1c ~ d1$att | d1$status, 
            boxplots = "xy", regLine=FALSE, fill=d1$status, cex=2)
```

resulting in the following graph:

[image]

Comment: This is great but I would need to plot a joint distribution of a1c and du99, which I could visualize by plotting one of the variable on the x-axis, the other on the y-axis and color the dots by case/control status. How would I do this?

Comment: sorry it's att and a1c

Comment: thanks, do you load scatterplot3d for this or from where do you get function scatterplot?

Comment: Thanks! I also tried to do it via: ggplot(df1, aes(x = att, y = a1c)) + geom_boxplot()+
geom_point(aes(color=status), position = position_dodge(width = .1), size= 1) but I don't know how to make this scattered dots bore vertical. I want to have basically two vertical streams of green and red dots for cases and controls

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help.

Comment: yes, and that you so much for your valuable inputs. Does this title sounds right?